# Как найти самый длинный маршрут в неориентированном графе без петель?

Tags: python, алгоритм, дерево, graph, dfs

Необходимо решить задачу:

Маленький мальчик делает бусы. У него есть много пронумерованных бусинок. Каждая бусинка имеет уникальный номер - целое число в диапазоне от 1 до N. Он выкладывает все бусинки на полу и соединяет бусинки между собой произвольным образом так, что замкнутых контуров не образуется. Каждая из бусинок при этом оказывается соединенной с какой-либо другой бусинкой. Требуется определить, какое максимальное количество последовательно соединенных бусинок присутствует в полученной фигуре.

Входные данные В первой строке входного файла 1 <= N <= 2500 - количество бусинок . В последующих N - 1 строках по два целых числа - номера, соединенных бусинок.

Выходные данные Вывести в файл одно число - искомое количество бусинок.

Примеры входные данные 5 2 1 2 3 2 4 2 5 выходные данные 3

Мой код падает на одном из тестов (run-time error)
В чем может быть проблема?

```
n = int(input())
l = []

for i in range(n - 1):
    l.append([int(i) for i in input().split()])

ways = []


for i in range(n):
    ways.append([])

for el in l:
    x, y = el
    ways[x - 1].append(y - 1)
    ways[y - 1].append(x - 1)

def dfs(graph, start, sum, arrAccum, visited=None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    visited.add(start)

    if (graph[start] - visited == set()):
        arrAccum.append(sum)
    else:
        sum += 1
      
    for next in graph[start] - visited:
        dfs(graph, next, sum, arrAccum, visited)


graph = dict.fromkeys(range(n))

for i in range(len(ways)):
    graph[i] = set(ways[i])

node_accum = []
graph_accum = []

for el in range(n):
    node_accum = []
    dfs(graph, el, 1, node_accum)
    graph_accum.extend(node_accum)

print(max(graph_accum))
```

Comment: Глубина рекурсии превышает 1000. Питон падает с переполнением стека.

Comment: В остальном ваш код выглядит рабочим. Сложность *n^2*. Задачу можно решить за *n*.

Comment: Неориентированный граф без петель с *n* вершинами и *n-1* ребром - это дерево. Длиннейший путь - его диаметр. Вы решаете задачу поиска диаметра дерева.

Answer (score 0):

Если граф является несвязным, то `graph_accum` будет содержать несколько значений, и функция `max()` выберет из них максимальное. Однако максимальное количество последовательно соединенных бусинок должно быть определено только наибольшим значением в `graph_accum`.

Чтобы исправить эту ошибку, замените строку:

```
print(max(graph_accum))
```

на

```
print(max(graph_accum) if graph_accum else 1)
```

Здесь, если `graph_accum` пустой (то есть граф несвязный), выводится 1, потому что в этом случае есть по крайней мере одна последовательность из одной бусинки.

Comment: `if graph_accum` всегда истинно. Даже если нет, это не причина для ошибки времени выполнения.